# How to clear this properly in IE 7?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a div container with a series of p tags.  Each p tag will float to the left.  **I want two p tags per line**, so think field/value.

**Title**: Some Title
 **Author**: Some Author

```
 <div id="container">
  <p class="field">Title</p><p>Some Title</p>
  <p class="field">Author</p><p>Some Author</p>
 </div>
```

If I set the "field" class to clear: both, I get the desired functionality in most browsers except IE 7 (not worried < 7).  However, in IE 7 if the containing div is wide enough, the clear: both seems to be ignored and I'll get something like this:

**Title**: Some title **Author**:
 Some Author

A couple of thoughts:

1. I can monitor the width of the containing div so that only two p tags can sit on one line but that seems very brittle.
2. I can muddy up the markup by placing clearing divs after every two p tags.  It would work but makes me feel dirty inside.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: option 2 solves your problem, it doesn't seem something to make you feel dirty, it's a structure element, that's all.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/g9Bvb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QUL9v/1/

Using the p tags....

```
<div id="container">
    <p class="field">Title</p><p class="field">Some Title</p><div class="clear"></div>
    <p class="field">Author</p><p class="field">Some Author</p><div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.field {
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

This is just sticking to the use of the p tag.  Personally, this is how I would accomplish it (http://jsfiddle.net/QUL9v/3/):

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="field">Title</div>
    <div class="field">Some Title</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="field">Author</div>
    <div class="field">Some Author</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The only reason I'm recommending this is because since this is more of a layout issue, it feels more natural to me to use the div as opposed to p element.  Also, it will ensure the position of the text, regardless of what you put inside the divs (anchors, forms, tables, etc).

Another thing you should pay attention to is I'm using the clear as the last sibling instead of the first (as in your examples).  If you're clearing the front; then its possible that since your trailing elements are floated and inline, you're going to potentially run into errors down the road, especially with IE7.  A lot of the times, the floating rule will get passed on to elements you never intended or thought it would be passed to.  Clearing at the end ensures that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  After some more thought the clearing divs aren't so bad.  There will be cases where I have two field/values on a single line, so having the flexibility to not break at every two is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use this pattern (span is optional - for additional styling if needed). Lists make more semantic sense than re-purposing the wrong tags. This is a list. :)

```
<ul>
    <li><label>Title</label><span>Some Title</span></li>
     ...
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul, li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none
}  

li {
   clear:both
}

label {
   float:left;
   width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to just leave out the floats in the situation? labels are inline elements so they should automatically "float" left of the span.

Comment: You need this to give LABEL a fixed width to make two columns. If two columns are not required then you can leave out FLOAT.

Comment: To give the label a fixed width wouldn't you need to make it `display: block;`?

Comment: Oh interesting, I guess floated elements automatically change elements to block type. http://jsfiddle.net/nJJ8p/2/